# Why is this onclick event not working in my script?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a script that makes it so a link will appear in a random position on each page visit. I have another script with a function for a list of random links so that once the link is clicked, you will be led to a random page.

However something is wrong because when clicking on this link, it does not lead you anywhere (the onClick doesn't seem to work). What can I do to fix it?

```
<script>
var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.left = left+'%';
    a.href = '#';
    a.onClick = "randomlinks()";
    a.innerHTML = 'click me';
document.body.appendChild(a)
</script>

<script src="randomlinks.js"></script>
```

The function works fine if I'm putting it as:

```
<a href='#' onclick='randomlinks();'>click me</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `a.onClick = "randomlinks()";`to `a.onclick = randomlinks;`

There is typo in your `onclick`. Also, you have to provide function reference to `onclick` event handler instead of `string`.

```js
var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

function randomlinks() {
  console.log('clicked');
}

var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = '#';
    a.style.right = left+'%';
    a.onclick = randomlinks;
    a.innerHTML = 'click me';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

```css
a {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: The random position script doesn't work when doing it this way.

Comment: You need to set position to absolute or relative. Check the updated snippet.